# How to override weblogic(12.2.1.4) default jar files with the jar files in your BPEL project?

Tags: apache-poi, weblogic, weblogic12c, soa, bpel

We have weblogic-12.2.1.4 version running which comes with apache poi-3.17 by default and this is the oracle approved poi jar version. I am facing certain issues when the same is used in my project so my requirement is to override this poi version. I have created a BPEL project and have java embedded activity added in it and i placed that java jar file at SCA-INF folder. The jar file in question here has poi 4.* added in it and also mentioned in the jar file's classpath.
When the BPEL project is deployed on weblogic, it is still referring the version 3.17. Can you please help me understand how can i make my project refer the jar files added in BPEL project rather than looking for the ones on weblogic server?

Also, I kept the external jar(poi) files at a server location and added that location under BPELCClasspath under MBean Properties. But it is still the same behavior.

Comment: You could read https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=loading-configuring-class-loaders-server - you may find that parent last classloading would fix this.